# How do you group social network nodes?

Tags: graph, social-networking, k-means

A graph is made up of nodes/vertexes connected by edges/arcs. Multiple sub groups of nodes often exist (colored below). These can be people in a social network, items and purchase records, travel data, or many other things.

[image]

How do you:

1. Split the nodes into groups based on edges
2. find the leader (most connected node) in each subgroup?

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question, you can use one of several community structure algorithms, such as:

- Minimum-cut method
- Hierarchical clustering
- Girvan–Newman algorithm
- Modularity maximization
- Among others.

As for your second question, once you know the members within a group you can rank them by number of connections.

Comment: Among the methods cited for the first question I'd add the following: other clusterings methods (DBScan, k-means, etc .... [sk-learn.cluster](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering) has a nice bunch of them), but also graph partitioning methods such as spectral partitioning, graph bisection ... in this case you can check [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview), it's rather efficient in what it does.